# User Defined Build Message in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I know in Visual C++ 2010, we can use #pragma message() to output something to the output window during a build.  But, since the #pragma is a pre-processor directive, the information is restricted to those known during the pre-processing phase.  Are there any techniques to output something based on the compile time information e.g. after a "int c;" declaration, I may want to output a message like "var c is declared".

Comment: There are unlimited ways to make good use of this. But, first of all, is it really possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `static_assert(condition, message);`?

Comment: not really, static_assert() will abort the build if the 'condition' is false. I just want to collect useful information about the src code and let the build finishes naturally.

Comment: Sounds like you want to take advantage of the insider knowledge that the compiler has after it parsed the program.  Similar to the way Roslyn works for C# and VB.NET.  The C++ compiler does not have anything remotely similar.

Comment: You'll probably be better off with libaries from [clang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422625/using-clang-to-analyze-c-code) then, unless you're looking for something like [SAL Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx).